# Poisson Equation with negative order inhomogeneous term

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

For $f\in H^{-1}(\Omega)$ Lax Milgram gives us a solution in $H^{1}_0$ to $\Delta u=f$.

What theory exists for $f\in W^{-1,p}$ or $f\in W^{-2,p}$ where $1<p<\infty$? Any references?